# mod_expires doesn't work with mod_pagespeed enabled

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, mod-expires

When trying to perform well in Google's Pagespeed insights, we've hit a situation.

We enabled mod_pagespeed and that worked. It did what it's supposed to do.

However, when looking at the results, on GT Metrix and Pagespeed Insights when we have mod_pagespeed enabled, mod_expires and browser caching doesn't work.

Is this by design? If so, is there anything globally or via .htaccess to I can code in to make browser caching happen?

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem, **also my css links that are indeed moved to footer by pagespeed's prioritize_critical_css are causing render-blocking error**.
It happens even if I set pagespeed to ONLY do above-the-fold css optimization:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeed On
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough
ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css
</IfModule>
```

When I set ModPagespeed Off, problem dissapears... For now I see browser caching warning for png images mostly (I have mod_expires set to "access 1 year", but when I'm trying to use extend_cache in pagespeed instead mod_exipre, even more browser caching warnings appear).

After some google search i found this removed the warning from insights:

```
ModPagespeedInPlaceResourceOptimization off
```

Docs on [In-Place Resource Optimization](https://modpagespeed.com/doc/system#ipro).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer, by Matthias Redl-Mann, I discovered in google products forum:

> So I could solve the problem: The apache user had no access to the
>   cache directory. Setting a different Cache Path via the 
>   ModPagespeedFileCachePath directive solved the problem. After setting
>   a path with access for the apache user, everything worked.